# In Python, Best way to sleep awaiting a callback

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep, wakeup

I am writing some python wrappers for a c++ library that speaks to a hardware device.  The general model of the library is to register a callback routine, then send a command to the hardware and await the callback.

I could simply loop checking a variable which gets set by the callback routine, but that feels stupid, as the program calling the wrappers may some day like to do other stuff while waiting.  So I would rather sleep on a semaphore and have the callback do a wakeup on the semaphore so that we can get all multi-threaded in the future.

Is that a thing in Python?  I am new to Python, but have experience with multi-threaded c and c++ device drivers. I would like pointers to a clean way to do this in Python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout concurrent.futures ? ThreadPoolExecutor could be an option

Comment: [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) is the most basic way of handling that. There are more higher-level mechanisms, for example `asyncio` and its [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Using an atomic message queue like [queue.Queue()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) is nice because if you call `.get(...)` on it while it is empty, it will automatically wait on a semaphore until someone (like your callback function) calls `.put(...)`.